# 'Refire' jQuery every second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code adds a class to the last div:

```
$(".mydivs:last").addClass('added');
```

This works on page load but the divs are in an animation, so the order changes. Is there a way to make the code run every second, so the class is added to the last div each time?

For me I dont think it matters that eventually every div will have the new class.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use animation or:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $(".mydivs:last").toggleClass('added');
},1000); // add or remove class `added` after every one second; two change the duration you can chage the value of `1000`
```

Answer (score 2):

As Peeter suggested, you can add a callback to the animation, for example:

```
jQuery.fadeIn(2000, function() {
  $(this).addClass("added");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`setInterval`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval) to do this.

```
setInterval(addNewClass, 1000);

function addNewClass() {
    $(".mydivs:last").addClass('added');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback to the animation instead.

Comment: Im using a plug in which I dont think allows for that. I know its a bit messy but whats the practice downside to my work around? Thanks